# Windows 10: Windows deleted all audio devices and soundcard - driver reinstall fails

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card, asus-laptop

I took an action which caused all of my onboard audio devices to be deleted by Windows, and I am stuck in getting them back:

What I've done:

1. I found an old analog microphone (really analog, just a small microphone with a standard jack from around 2004) and plugged into the audio jack on my Windows 10 laptop to see if it would work (presuming it would just do nothing)
2. I went to audio devices and to my suprise there was a new option that said something like "new audio device (unknown)". I clicked it and windows opened a dialog that said something like "do you want to set up this device". I clicked yes, and shortly afterwards the dialog said I'd need to restart for the changes to take effect.
3. I kept the computer on for a while and I *believe* at this time my on-board audio still existed.
4. I restarted after 5-10 minutes and once I restarted again the audio icon showed an 'x' and I couldn't find any on-board audio device (playback and recording) anywhere in any dialog.

Here is my empty sound devices within windows settings:

[Manage Audio Devices showing no devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLut1.png)

Here is the 'Sound' tab of DxDg showing no devices or soundcard:

[DirectX Diagnosis tool showing no devices/soundcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YkHz.png)

What I've done that hasn't worked:

1. Restarted the computer several times
2. Run audio troubleshooting tools from every windows tab I could find (the majority of them require you to choose a device to troubleshoot and show me an empty list. At least one did run and had no positive effect).
3. Downloaded and attempted to install every version of this laptop's audio driver (Connexant Audio 8.66.different.subversion // ASUS VivoBook 15 X510UA
   ) from my manufacturer's website. One of the drivers doesn't seem to run, and has no result. Three of the drivers run and failed with the message

   > Driver Installation Failed: Could not find the device for this driver

   Here is the failure message:

   [image: ERROR dialog hovering over driver installer window]

I'm out of ideas and detailed googling hasn't helped me find a solution - I would really appreciate the community's help.

Comment: 1. Restore from last disk image. 2. Try SFC and DISM repairs. 3. Download Windows ISO and repair... it should find drivers.

Comment: There could be a Windows System Restore point you could roll back to.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the driver you installed?